# Are there any tools to auto-generate an ERD diagram from a json representation of a db schema?

Tags: database, erd

I'm working on a [QuickBase](http://quickbase.intuit.com) application and I'd like to be able to generate an image representing the table structure of the application.

I can generate a list of tables and the relationships between them in any fashion needed - I just need a library that will tell me what format to feed my schema and have it spit out an ERD image of the schema.

Does something like this exist? Preferably, it would be something I could script because I'll be using the QuickBase API to generate the schema. Bonus if it will also let me display the fields, unique/primary or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

QuickBase recently released the relationship diagram in the product. You can view the table relationship and also drag around tables to define your layout. It also gives you feature like table information (links to fields page, number of fields) and option to show the primary key field involved in the relationship.

Here is the link to the help documentation
[relationship diagram](http://www.quickbase.com/user-assistance/Default.html%23relationship_diagram.html)